# How do I dynamically update the fields of a document?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm building a basic crud app for storing movie/tv titles. I am using version 2.4.4 of elasticsearch because my project manager chose this version.  I am using the express framework along with the native elasticsearch nodejs driver.

Currently this is what my mappings look like for the "titles" index for a "title" type.

```
client.indices.create({
      index: "titles",
      body: {
        "mappings": {
          "title": {
            "properties": {
              "seriesName":           { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
              "seriesEpisodeNumber":  { "type": "long", "index": "not_analyzed" },
              "seriesEpisodeTitle":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
              "isDeleted":            { "type": "boolean", "index": "not_analyzed" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }).
```

I want to have an endpoint on my server that updates the document by its id. This is what I have so far for this endpoint " POST /api/titles/:titleID/updateTitleByID"

```
titlesController.updateTitleByID = function(req,res){
  const titleID = req.params.titleID;
  es.updateByQuery({
    index: "titles",
    type: "title",
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [{
            term: {
              _id: titleID
            }},{
              term: {
                isDeleted: false 
              }}]
        }
      },
      script: {
        inline: "ctx._source.seriesName = seriesName;ctx._source.seriesEpisodeNumber = seriesEpisodeNumber; ctx._source.seriesEpisodeTitle = seriesEpisodeTitle;",
        params: { ...req.body }
      }
    }}).then(results => {
      logger.info(results);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "OK"
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      logger.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: "Internal server error"
      });
    });
};
```

What I want to achieve is to update the document with what ever I get from my req.body. For example if I get a seriesName I from the request body. That is only what I want to update and leave the rest untouched. How do I achieve this?

Edit: Here is the full stack trace

```
Error: [remote_transport_exception] [Agon][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]
    at respond (/home/natealcedo/Projects/digitalfolks.hooq/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:289:15)
    at checkRespForFailure (/home/natealcedo/Projects/digitalfolks.hooq/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:248:7)
    at HttpConnector.<anonymous> (/home/natealcedo/Projects/digitalfolks.hooq/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:164:7)
    at IncomingMessage.wrapper (/home/natealcedo/Projects/digitalfolks.hooq/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4968:19)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the update-by-query endpoint if you want to update a single document, the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update.html) is more than sufficient since it supports [partial updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document), which is exactly what you're after. You need to use the [`update` call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-2-4.html#api-update-2-4) instead:

```
titlesController.updateDocByID = function(req,res){
  const titleID = req.params.titleID;
  const partialFields = req.body;
  // TODO do some validations on the received fields
  es.update({
    index: "titles",
    type: "title",
    id: titleID,
    body: {
      doc: partialFields
    }}).then(results => {
      logger.info(results);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "OK"
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      logger.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: "Internal server error"
      });
    });
};
```

If you need to only update the document if the `isDeleted` flag is false, then you can use the same API call but with a script instead, like this:

```
titlesController.updateDocByID = function(req,res){
  const titleID = req.params.titleID;
  const partialFields = req.body;
  // TODO do some validations on the received fields
  es.update({
    index: "titles",
    type: "title",
    id: titleID,
    body: {
      script: "if (!ctx._source.isDeleted) { ctx._source.putAll(params.partialFields) }",
      params: {partialFields: partialFields}
    }}).then(results => {
      logger.info(results);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "OK"
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      logger.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: "Internal server error"
      });
    });
};
```

If you use this second method, you'll need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file.

Comment: This works. Thank you so much! :) could You point me in the direction for scripting? I didn't know there was a method .putall

Comment: `ctx._source` refers to the source document which is a Java Map, hence in Groovy you can use the `putAll` method.

Comment: Hey sorry can you help me out? When I tried your method, it throws an error Error: [remote_transport_exception] [Agon][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]

Comment: I'm puzzled as you said it worked in your first comment ?! Feel free to update your question with the full stack trace.

Comment: I actually thought it would work. I never really tested it. I was away from my pc for the whole day attending to other matters. Here is the full stack trace. It's in the original post

Comment: I'm interested to see the stack trace you get in the ES server logs, not the one on the client side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139243/discussion-between-nate-and-val).

Comment: lets chait in the chat created